# Javascript - can't use object methods when called inside a function thats running through interval?

Tags: javascript, object, setinterval, intervals

I'm getting undefined function when I try to do the following (simplified for readability)

```
function object() {
  this.bar = function() { };

  this.foo = function() {
    this.bar();
  };

  this.z = setInterval(this.foo, 1000);

}
```

This code gives 'undefined function this.bar()' when executed from within the interval, but not when this.foo is called outside of the interval.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct - you can't do it that way.  The `this` pointer will not be set correctly when called from `setInterval()` (it is probably set to point to the global `window` object).  You can change your code like this to solve the problem:

```
function object() {
  this.bar = function() { };

  this.foo = function() {
    this.bar();
  };
  var self = this;   // save reference to local object in variable other than 'this'

  this.z = setInterval(function() {
    self.foo();      // call method on local object
  }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: +1 for using "self" instead of the horrible "that" that I keep seeing everywhere.

Comment: @nnnnnn, self is actually bad since self refers to the window object. [MDC window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self)

Comment: @epascarello - I don't see that as a problem, since I would never use `window.self` without the `window.` part, and for code like jfriend00's `self` would always be a local variable so there would be no conflict. But you could say `_this` or `thisObj` or `me` or something instead; just don't use `that` since the word means the opposite of what the variable is for.

Comment: @epascarello In this case `self` is a local variable so it is distinct from `window.self`.

Comment: Using self is sort of like using setInterval or any other part of window. Would you use those as variable names? :D

Comment: `myObject.self` has essentially the same purpose within myObject as `window.self` has for window, and I see that as a _good_ thing, not something to be avoided. I would have no hesitation giving my objects a `name` property either, even though there is a `window.name`. Nor does it bother me that `window` has a `length` property even though arrays do too. Of the many, many properties and methods that `window` has there are only about six that I would use without the `window.` prefix, those being alert, confirm, setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval and clearInterval.